# find if exist element with webdriverjs

Tags: javascript, bdd, webdriverjs

We have problems when checked if a element exist in the page

Example

```
return driver.wait(function() {
                driver.findElement(By.css(".class")).then(function(element){
                                      if(element){
                                        return true;
                                      }
                                    },function(error){
                                        if(error){
                                          return false;
                                        }
                                  });
                }, 2000);
```

In this function the 2000 seconds timeout never is executed and we obtains timeout from webdriver

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to check that an element exists, or wait until the element exists? These are two different things.

**Check Element Exists:**

```
driver.isElementPresent(webdriver.By.css('.class')).then(function(present) {
   console.log(present);
});
```

**Wait For An Element To Exist**

```
driver.wait(webdriver.until.elementLocated(webdriver.By.css('.class')), 2000);
```

Comment: i couldn't find an `isElementPresent` method in the selenium docs. is this answer still valid?